# How to increase MaxReceivedMessageSize for azure worker role deployment?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services

I have an azure worker role which is medium size and one instance. I encountered an error which says "**The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (1048576) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.**" when deploying my azure worker role cloud service to azure using visual studio.

I tried to increase maxReceivedMessageSize property in app.config like this but it didn't work:

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttp" allowCookies="true"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483648" 
                 maxBufferSize="2147483648"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483648">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" 
                 maxArrayLength="2147483648"
                 maxStringContentLength="2147483648"/>
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The highest permittable number for the max* numbers is 2147483647, not 2147483648 which you have listed. Your config should look like this:

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttp" allowCookies="true"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" 
                 maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                 maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: I changed max numbers as you suggested but it didn't solve the problem:(

Answer (score 0):

I am having the exact problem. Apparently, it is a problem with Azure itself (see: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6b895c6b-69e3-4211-ab2f-29b95ff23030/unable-to-publish-web-role-maxreceivedmessagesize-error?forum=windowsazuredevelopment).

The problem was marked as fixed in the link above. However, today, I am still getting the exact same problem. I had to upload the package manually :(

Cheers