# Azure deployment showing error "The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (1048576) has been exceeded."

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-cloud-services

There is error while deploying cloud service and Deployment fails. Any idea how to fix this.

[Smiler Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32454252/how-to-increase-maxreceivedmessagesize-for-azure-worker-role-deployment) with no satisfying answer.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is happening when the log size exceeds 65536.
You can delete the old logs after downloading , so the command continues to work if the size of the file is below the threshold.

Comment: Thanks for help! Which log file we are looking into? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Avi Take look at this thread . https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/26